# Accessibility does not read the keyboard buttons

Tags: android, keyboard, accessibility

I have activated the TalkBack (Accessibility). And I'm navigating for a Screen that is displayed a keyboard in order to write a number in my app.

When I swipe from the left to the right in order to hear all items available the announcement read all my UI components but never jump to the KeyBoard Buttons. So the users will ever know there is a keyboard displayed in the UI.

I have tested on iOS and the VoiceOver is reading the Keyboard properly but seems like Android have an issue.

Does anyone know if there is a way to activate the Keyboard Voice Feedback programmatically?

I'm using this code to show the keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager)
            activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
input.showSoftInput(activity.getCurrentFocus(), InputMethodManager
            .SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard is a separate app in Android.  It would need to implement accessibility itself.

Comment: So, are you saying that the Keyboard does not have accessibility implemented?

Comment: Most likely.  Or it has some option for it.  Either way its not something you can effect programatically.  Also note that its not the Keyboard, its this keyboard app.  There's lots of those.